# Select2 Krajee widget - using modal and getting the id of the value

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2-4

What is the way to get the value of the select item with modal. As it is shown in demo example (Using a `select2` widget inside a modal dialog):

```
Modal::begin([
'options' => [
    'id' => 'kartik-modal',
    'tabindex' => false // important for Select2 to work properly
],
'header' => '<h4 style="margin:0; padding:0">Select2 Inside Modal</h4>',
'toggleButton' => ['label' => 'Show Modal', 'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary'],
]);


echo Select2::widget([
'name' => 'state_40',
'data' => $data,
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
],
]);
Modal::end();
```

I get the options to be shown and select, but I need id of the selected value to be saved somewhere so I can get it to be forwarded as part of the link in button.

For example:

```
Html::button('Example', ['value' => Url::to(['example/example', 'id' => ?]),'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary ']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a easy way. I´ve done it many times.

```
'options' => [
                'class'=>'col-md-3','id'=>'id_select',
                'placeholder' => 'Select the country',
             ],
```

with jquery :

```
var id_select = $('#id_select').val();
```

Or if you prefer ajax:

```
      echo  Html::a('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Send',null,[
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
    'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Enviar'),
    'onclick'=>"
     var id_select = $('#id_select').val();
     $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        cache    : false,
        url  : '".Url::toRoute(['example'])."&id='+id_select,
        success  : function(response) {
          //ok      
        },
        error: function() {
          alert('Error');
        }
     });
]);
```

you can´t get all parameters with php, you need client languaje for get this.
However I´d invite you to use `<form>` with model, is more easy and fast.

Comment: Thank you! I listened to your advice and use it with model, it was  easier.